# What's the etymology of the Albanian word for hello, "tungjatjeta"?

Tags: etymology, albanian

In Albanian the usual greeting is "**tungjatjeta**", what is it derived or descended from? What are its origins?

Comment: I think this is off-topic. See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics/6678#6678.

Comment: @AlekStorm: You linked to ["What does \[word\] mean in \[language\]?"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics/6678#6678). This question is not about definition or translation, it's about etymology.

Comment: Yes, it feels too specific. Talking about language-specific phenomena is perfectly acceptable, but the etymology of one word is inapplicable to the rest of linguistics.

Comment: Well this also works as a test question for deciding what the site's scope is. The answers to [this question on meta](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/118/overlap-of-linguistics-site-vs-the-languages-site-proposal-vs-individual-language) seems to suggest that a question that would be on-topic on a SE site for a single language should also be on-topic here. You might want to weigh in with an opinion on that page.

Comment: There is a vague continuum between historical linguistics and lexicography, but I have to agree with @Alek that this question falls on the wrong side of the dividing line.

Comment: @Aaron: Please weigh in with your opinion on meta where it will be useful for development of the site too: http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/118/overlap-of-linguistics-site-vs-the-languages-site-proposal-vs-individual-language

Comment: I've now posed a specific question on meta about which etymology questions would be within the site's scope: http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/143/which-etymology-questions-should-be-within-or-topic-scope

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Albanian, but according to this [old wikipedia entry of "Tung"](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tung&direction=prev&oldid=369325067), it apparently comes from something like 'long-life-to-you'.

It was finally [removed](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tung&diff=next&oldid=345881362) by someone, using the edit summary "tidy".

Comment: I'm albanian, it means long life to you like so:

Tu -> To you
Ngjate -> may it become longer 
Jeta -> The life

Comment: Live long and prosper. :)